# Testing asp.net website via IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am trying to test my asp.net application via IIS however i receive this error upon testing via the browser

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.



Detailed Error Information:



Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   BeginRequest 

Handler
   Not yet determined 

Error Code
   0x80070021 

Config Error
   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".  

Config File
   \\?\C:\inetpub\Domains\Website\web.config 



Requested URL
   http://ww2.website.co.za:80/ 

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\Domains\website 

Logon Method
   Not yet determined 

Logon User
   Not yet determined 




Config Source:
    8:  <system.webServer>
    9:   <handlers>
   10:    <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
```

The asp.net application works fine, but when moving it to a new web server and testing via it the error appears. Is there any changes that needs to be made to my web.config file ?

Guys i've done a lot of research on this and it doesnt seem to be related to my web.config file

Is there any other solution to this ? maybe via IIS ?

Comment: do you have .net framework installed on your web server?

Comment: how did you deploy the application?

Comment: Yes i do have .net framework installed. I deployed the application via the IIS manager(set the default document, check the application pool settings etc)